# How to upgrade python version 2.5.5 to 2.6.8 in Solaris 11

Tags: upgrade, python, solaris

I am using **SunOS 5.11 Solaris**. Currently I have python version 2.5.5. I would like to upgrade it to 2.6.8. Can someone please help me on the steps to follow for this upgrade? Please note, I need the steps specifically for `upgrading from 2.5.5 to 2.6.8` in `Sun Solaris 5.11`.

**EDIT**
command cat /etc/release shows

```
Copyright (c) 2011 Oracle. All Rights Reserved. Use is subject to license terms. uname -a SunOS 5.11 i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris uname -r 5.11 python --version Python 2.5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

In the actual Solaris 11 release, python 2.5 is obsolete and python 2.6.8 is installed by default, so if you have python 2.5.5 and not 2.6, you must be running an older release, such as one of the releases of Solaris Express or the OpenSolaris distro.

`cat /etc/release` can give better details on which release you're really running.

Comment: I given the command  
  
cat /etc/release  
  
Copyright (c) 2011 Oracle. All Rights Reserved.  
Use is subject to license terms.  
  
uname -a  
SunOS 5.11 i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris  
  
uname -r  
5.11  
  
python --version  
Python 2.5.5

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question.  Solaris 11.2 is already using Python 2.6.8 by default.

Your output from `cat /etc/release` is truncated and therefore meaningless. Here's what my `/etc/release` file looks like:

```
                             Oracle Solaris 11.2 X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
                             Assembled 23 June 2014
```

(Your output is missing the top line)

Python version on Solaris 11.2:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.6.8
```

I'm not sure but I believe previous versions of Solaris 11.x had Python 2.6.8 on them as well. Should this not be the case then simply update to Solaris 11.2 by issuing following commands from root account:

```
pkg update --accept
reboot
```

The above commands will update your system to Solaris 11.2. It will work if your existing OS level is 11.0 or 11.1. You can see your OS level from the top line of the `/etc/release` file.